# Pixel per square foot

Tags: image-processing

I was reading about pixel per foot but can someone teach how can i calculate the pixel per foot?
If given the resolution 640(horizontal) x 480(vertical), lens range from 2.8 mm - 12 mm, distance = 16ft (around 5 meter) and pixel per foot equals to?

Anyone?

Comment: Interesting question but not enough information to understand exactly what you are trying to calculate. You say pixel per square foot but you have the answer of 25. Is it the distance you are trying to figure out?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just edit back the question. Btw, what information is lack of?

Comment: Well your edits give more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean - you want to calculate how wide an image is in real-world units?

If you know the angle of the field of view `f`, and the distance to the target `d`, you can calculate the width `w` of plane visible at that distance with a bit of trig.

```
    <------------------w-------------------->                                               
    *****************************************                    
     *                ^ * <-----o------>   *                          
      *               | *                 *                           
       *              | *                *                            
        *             | *               *                             
         *            | *              *                              
          *           | *             *                               
           *          | *            *                                
            *         d *           *                                 
             *        | *          *                                  
              *       | *         *                                   
               *      | *        *                                    
                *     | *       *                                     
                 *    | * f/2  *                                      
                  *   | *     *                                       
                   *  | *    *                                        
                    * v *   *                                         
                     *  *  *                                          
                      * * *                                           
                       ***                                            
                        *
```

So, remember the old school SOH CAH TOA? `tan(angle) = opposite / adjacent`. We want to calculate the opposite dimension `o`, and we know that the adjacent is `d` and the angle is is `f/2`, so we get `o = tan(f/2) * d`

`o` is half the width, so we double it to give our final calculation of `w = d * tan(f/2) * 2`

So, now you know the real-world width `w` of the plane `d` units from the camera, and you know your image is `p` pixels wide, the pixels-per-unit is simply `p/w`

The only problem that remains is calculating the field of view angle `f` from the focal length of the lens - that's a little more specialised. This depends on the camera, particularly the size of the image sensor. You can generate a table for many popular cameras here http://www.howardedin.com/articles/fov.html.

If you know the size of the image sensor, or are using 36mmx24mm film negatives, you can use  [this formula](http://kmp.bdimitrov.de/technology/fov.html) to calculate the FOV for a "normal" rectilinear lens:

```
fieldOfView = 2 * arctan (sensorWidth / (2 * focalLength))
```

Comment: I'm not quite understand it. I have the (1). distance, (2). lens range (lets say 5mm) , (3). horizontal pixel (640), with this kind of information, is it enough to determine the pixel per foot?

Comment: Thank you for the information Paul Dixon. From the reading, pixels per foot means the amount of details or resolution in a specific area of the image and does the width here referring to the horizontal resolution of the camera?

Comment: According to the last link, a 5mm lens gives an FOV of 153 degrees. So, planewidth=distance-to-plane * tan(153/2) * 2, and pixels per unit is pixelwidth/planewidth

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean now. Let me have a try first and update it later.

Comment: Nice description, complete with ASCII-art. I'm positive that the camera doesn't use a 36x24mm sensor, it's probably much much smaller than that, meaning 153 degrees is a misleading figure. Also the web site states that's a diagonal measure, not the width.

Comment: The OP could work out the sensor size if he knows the focal length by taking a photo under controlled conditions and measuring the fov.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to actually take a picture of a 1-foot ruler and open it in an image editing program, and count the number of pixels from one end to the other.

Comment: How is that so? A pixel equals to 1 mm?

Comment: @MizukiKai, you want to know how many pixels are in a foot. The most direct way to calculate it is to measure how many pixels are in a foot. This has nothing to do with mm.

Comment: Mathematically, 1 ft = 0.3048 m. In image how can I represent the pixel in ft?

Comment: Either I'm understanding either the question or this answer incorrectly, or this answer is _way_ wrong. Apologies, Mark, for the emphasis - not trying to be rude. This answer will _only_ hold if the camera that is being used to take a picture of the 1ft ruler is always the same (or at least, a camera with the exact same resolution is used) and it is always the _exact_ same distance from the ruler. I've just put together an excel calculator to determine PPF from a set of variables (hence why I'm here), and although I haven't read through it entirely, Paul's answer seems much more correct.

Comment: @MandM you're correct, this assumes that all the aspects of the system (camera, lens, distance to subject, etc) remain the same after measurement. Paul's answer is great on a theoretical level but doesn't account for real-world issues; for example the focal length of a lens will vary from the nominal value and change when you change the focal point, so converting from that to an angle of view is a non-trivial exercise.